# Devise 2.0.4, Rails 3.2.3 - After creating user account I am redirected to root and can't access other routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I'm coming from Sinatra to Rails and still quite new to Rails. My problem is that after I create a User account I am just directed to the index.html page in the /public folder and can't seem to access any other routes, I can't sign_out the user and I can't add another user.

I am using the devise gem to manage my user model and authentication. After installing the gem I followed the instructions on the devise github page.

ie:

```
rails generate devise:install
```

I also added to the 'config/environments/development.rb' file

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

and I added to the 'config/routes.rb' file

```
root :to => "home#index"
```

and I added to the 'app/views/layouts/application.html.erb' file

```
<p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
```

Then I ran

```
rails generate devise User
```

And finally

```
rake db:migrate
```

Here is my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
end
```

Then I navigated to "/users/sign_up" and I entered an email and password after which I was redirected to the index.html page in the public folder.

The problem is I just seem to be stuck there. '/users/sign_out' yields

```
Routing Error

No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

And running 'rake routes' yields

```
new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                    root        /                              home#index
```

Seems like '/users/sign_up' should be a working route.

I am wondering if the problem is that there is no email service setup and this account is trying to be validated trough email? If so, how do I disable that?

Thanks! And let me know if you need more information or for me to clarify something.

===============UPDATE===================

The 'users/edit' route does work and I think possibly the problem lies in the fact that the route that is setup for 'users/sign_out' is a DELETE route. I forget the terminology about this, but I know that there is some sort of trickery in making a DELETE route out of a GET route. So is this where my problem lies?

Comment: You need to delete the `index.html` file in the public folder as a first step.

Comment: Step 1 complete. Now I receive `Routing Error

uninitialized constant HomeController
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.` when i goto localhost:3000

Comment: You need to create a HomeController (in app/controllers/home_controller.rb) with an index action, and the views associated in app/views/home(/index.html.erb).

Comment: OK, sorry for being such a noob with this. Also, check out my "UPDATE" to the question. I think I may have narrowed the problem scope a good bit.

Comment: Have you looked at my answer yet?

Comment: I ran `rails generate controller home index` and that's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of two things here.

Create a link to do the logout, something like this:

`<%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>`

Or add an additional route like this to your `routes.rb` file:

```
    devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions]
    as :user do
        get 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
        post 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
        get 'signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
    end
```

The above example is from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes

Answer (score 0):

To sign out, you should be calling:

```
destroy_user_session_path
```

Devise stores sessions, and `DELETE` just removes your session.

For the routing error, can you post up your HomeController?

And for the `edit`, are you calling:

```
edit_user_registration_path
```

Comment: `rake routes` seems to be confirming that my routes are setup the way you are saying but I'm not sure where to go from there?

Comment: I added `<%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path %>` and clicking the "Sign Out" link takes me to '/users/sign_out" which gives the no-route error that I added to my update.

Answer (score 0):

A few moments ago I was having this problem and instead of looking for sites and more sites, it was when  i stop here and one of the codes shown above is also shown below worked fine for me thanks

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions]

as :user do
 get 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
 post 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
 get 'signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```

Comment: You should probably add this as a comment, not an answer to the question. But glad it helped, stackoverflow is great!